# Why does my pivot table not count show 0 as 0 when I want it to count how many items have 0 as a value?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a visual representation using an Excel Pivot Table of the progress of updating content on a website. Each item on my website has the age of the last time it was updated then another column that shows that it now is 0 years old or the same number because it was either updated or not. Not all have been updated so there are still some that are above 1. My problem is that the pivot table is showing 0 as 0 when I want to show how many items are age 0. There should be over 3,000 items that show 0 so I want the pivot table to show 3000. I for the life of me cannot figure out how to fix this.

I've tried changing the format to numbers, then to general, then converted text to column. Nothing is working and I've been trying for hours. What am I doing wrong? I want the table to be stacked bars that show 8 different rows (Ages 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,123) and 2 values for each showing the old age versus the new after updating some content. And I want 0 to be counted as an item not a value. I want to count how many items are 0 years old. I am definitely not a pro at this and I'm only just learning and teaching myself.

I also noticed that when I show the value as count, the before and after are the same value (which is not true) and when I do sum, they are different but it's adding the years together instead of counting how many items are 6,5,4,3,2,1,0 years old. (When it shows 123 years old, it is because it has not been updated at all yet)

Data Excerpt
[image]

Values set as sum
[image]

Values set at count
[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PeterT I just uploaded some screenshots. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I just updated the question title is that good now? I'm really struggling and this is a really important project I'm working on. I'm trying to word it the best I can but I am new to Excel and might not say the right things.

Comment: Add a helper column to your data that returns a "1" if the Age is 0 and a "0" if it isn't.  Then use that helper column in your pivot table to give you a count by summing it.

Comment: It would be much better to post your source data as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, given what you have posted as a `Data Excerpt`, how does one tell if something has been updated or not?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are right, I reuploaded the screenshot with the column titles.

Comment: Is the data set up as a table to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get exactly the chart you want, I'd set up a separate table that runs the counts for each year.

I created a sample data table like this ***(that is actually down to Row 100)***:

[image]

Then, in another area of your workbook (or on another worksheet), create a table like this:
[image]

Everything in color is entered by hand.

The formula is Column I is `=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$100,H2)`, copied down.

The formula is Column J is `=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$100,H2)`, copied down.

From that table, I created this chart:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That was really informative and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to display. But one way to obtain a `Count` of the `New Age`, that differentiates `0`, is to

- Drag `Age in Years` to Rows
- `New Age in Years` to Columns
- `New Age in Years` to Values

  - Value Field Settings => Count

You can then produce this pivot Graph from the data you posted:

[image]

If you want something different, please elaborate.